# Xcode 9 TextViewShouldReturn

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, xcode9, uitextviewdelegate

In the past, to dismiss the keyboard after a user hits return I would simply override the TextViewShouldReturn function. However, upon re-downloading Xcode (version 9.3.1) it seems it is no longer a function within UITextViewDelegate and most all previous questions I've found on the subject advise overriding TextViewShouldReturn in some way as well. Is there something I've forgotten or a more efficient way possibly?

This is what I'm currently looking at in my application:
[image: Not allowed to embed an image yet so here's a link]

Answer (score 3):

There is no method like textViewShouldReturn() for textView like textField, rather you can use the following code to return your keyboard-

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return true
        }
        return true
    }
```

// Make sure you have self the textView delegate in viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're confusing `UITextViewDelegate` with `UITextFieldDelegate`?

Comment: You're totally right. Always the silly mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `textViewShouldReturn` in UITextViewDelegates this function is of UITextField delegate so you have to create your own code for hide keyboard when click on return. By default in UITextView return button is used for next line.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to hide keyboard .try this

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    if ( [ text isEqualToString: @"\n" ] ) {
        [ textView resignFirstResponder ];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```